# Quotient of complex polynomials ( alhfors complex analysis)

Tags: complex-analysis, rational-functions

### The Problem

[image]

### My Work

We know that:

$\frac{Q'(z)}{Q(z)}=\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{(z-\alpha_k)}$

Thus

$\frac{P(z)}{Q(z)}=\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n}\frac{P(z)}{Q'(z)(z-\alpha_k)}$

This is about as far as I have traveled any ideas?

### Possible Ideas

I get the feeling that I should use :

[image]

But I am not sure of it's relevancy.

Comment: Also: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/101874/42969.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We know that, for some $K\in\mathbb{C}\setminus\{0\}$, $Q(z)=K(z-\alpha_1)(z-\alpha_2)\cdots(z-\alpha_n)$. So, by [partial fraction decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_fraction_decomposition), $\frac{P(z)}{Q(z)}$ can be written as$$\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{\beta_k}{z-\alpha_k}.$$Besides,$$\beta_k=\lim_{z\to\alpha_k}(z-\alpha_k)\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{\beta_k}{z-\alpha_k}=\lim_{z\to\alpha_k}\frac{P(z)}{\frac{Q(z)}{z-\alpha_k}}=\frac{P(\alpha_k)}{Q'(\alpha_k)}.$$

Comment: Why does $\beta_k=\lim\limits_{z\to \alpha_k}(z-\alpha_k)\sum\limits_{m=1}^{n}\frac{\beta_m}{z-\alpha_m}$?

Comment: I apologise I am on the mathstack app anyways I understand your answer.

Comment: @user160110 Because $\displaystyle\lim_{z\to\alpha_k}(z-\alpha_k)\frac{\beta_k}{z-\alpha_k}=\beta_k$ and, if $j\neq k$, $\displaystyle\lim_{z\to\alpha_k}(z-\alpha_k)\frac{\beta_j}{z-\alpha_j}=0\times\frac{\beta_j}{\alpha_k-\alpha_j}=0$.

Answer (score 1):

Let
$$R(z):=Q(z)\cdot\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{P(\alpha_k)}{Q'(\alpha_k)(z-\alpha_k)}=\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{P(\alpha_k)}{Q'(\alpha_k)}\cdot\frac{Q(z)}{z-\alpha_k}.$$
Then $R$ is a polynomial of degree $\leq n-1$ such that for $j=1,\dots,n$,
$$\lim_{z\to \alpha_j}R(z)=\sum_{k\not=j}
\frac{P(\alpha_k)Q(\alpha_j)}{Q'(\alpha_k)(\alpha_j-\alpha_k)}+
\frac{P(\alpha_j)}{Q'(\alpha_j)}\lim_{z\to \alpha_j}\frac{Q(z)}{z-\alpha_j}
=
\frac{P(\alpha_j)Q'(\alpha_j)}{Q'(\alpha_j)}=P(\alpha_j)$$
(recall that $Q(\alpha_k)=0$ and $Q'(\alpha_k)\not=0$ for $k=1,\dots,n$).

Hence the polynomials $P$ and $R$ coincide in $n$ points.
What may we conclude?